# {% block content %} {% endblock %} showing in html while making chatbot

Tags: python, django

I was following one chatbot tutorial using Django, I came across this error:

frontpage.html

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Welcome | {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="p-10 lg:p-20 text-center">
    <h1 class="text-3xl lg:text-6xl text-white">Djangochat</h1>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title> {% block title %}{% endblock %}Django </title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com" ></script> 
    
    <body class="bg-teal-600">
        <nav class="flex items-center justify-between px-4 py-6 bg-teal-800">
            <div>
                <a href="/" class="text-xl text-white">Djangochat</a> 
            </div>
            <div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
                <a href="/login/" class="text-white hover:text-gray-200">Log in</a>
                <a href="/signup" class="px-5 py-3 rounded-xl text-white bg-teal-700">Sign up</a>
            </div> 
        </nav>  
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}  
    </head>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gehss.png)

So, `{% block title %} {% end block %}` is not working, kindly help.

Comment: Please paste your code rather than the screenshots.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What @RahulKP said is true. Adding code snippets (using the backtick symbol \` or the button in the graphical editor) makes the answer easier to understand and allows other people to test your code.

Comment: I am sorry i convert it please tell me now

Answer (score 0):

Change the title to this on `base.html`

```
<title>{% block title %}my base page{% endblock %}</title>
```

Then go to `frontpage.html` or any page you want to

```
<title>{% block title %}my front page{% endblock %}</title>
```

As mentioned in the official documentation [The Django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/)

**EDIT**

You're mistaken about the form of HTML the close tag of the head in the body

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> {% block title %}{% endblock %}Django </title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com" ></script> 
</head>

<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The main problem is in between the body i did what you said the error is still there [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SF1k_Twr9cg) .This is the tutorial at 11:09 timestamp

Comment: `{% block content %} {% endblock %} `content is the variable name. You can name whatever you like.  However, that name will need to be posted on the new page. 
Search "Django Extends HTML" for continuation on this.